# how to work with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and newtonsoft.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core-2.0

I am doing the first of my asp.net projects, and we have settled on using asp.net core v. 2.0 - now that ms has released it. - we are using .NET 4.6 in our backed projects.
but I am having some problems with using Newtonsoft.json, that apparently doesn't support the .netstandard 2.0 in the version 10.0.1 that I've installed.
And for some unknown reason it will not install v.10.0.3, - I get this:

```
    Error   NU1202  Package Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) / win7-x64. Package Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.1 supports:
  - net20 (.NETFramework,Version=v2.0)
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netstandard1.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)    ScannerWebRemoteControl
```

any ideas anyone?

Comment: ASP.NET Core has an implicit dependency on `Newtonsoft.Json` - In most circumstances, you shouldn't need to add an explicit package reference. Having said that, you should still be able to. Try uninstalling your `Newtonsoft.Json` package and then install the 10.0.3 version. Your error message talks of 10.0.1 so it's unlikely anyone can use that to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Open **Integrated Terminal** and run code given below

`dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json`

It will download and add Newtonsoft.Json to the project (Latest version).

Answer (score 3):

Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0.3 still do not support for .NETStandard 2.0.
In ASP.NET CORE Microsoft has nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch which is for .NETStandard 2.0 and makes Newtonsoft.Json available for you.

So if you have new ASP.NET CORE 2.0 project with nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All it includes Newtonsoft.Json for you already (via Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch).

For .NET 4.x projects you need to add Newtonsoft.Json manually.

Answer (score 3):

```
dotnet add package  Newtonsoft.Json -v 11.0.2
```

will result to :

```
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your .csproj file and add

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: `11.0.2` is .net core compatible? It must be cross-platform and I'm having trouble finding documentation verifying the latest Newtonsoft is .net core compliant.

Answer (score 0):

try out this in Nuget.

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName> -ignoreDependencies
```

link [Nuget commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages)

good link to save.

Comment: try to use the commads to reinstall all the packages in your project. 
Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName <project_name> to reinstall all packages in the project.

Comment: I removed all the nuget packages I used, and added them again manually. - and low and behold - no need for json package...
and problem went away... didn't solve it though